# Building string in dynamic SQL - tricky quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, quotes, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to build a custom error message string for a bit of dynamic SQL. It looks like this when not wrapped in dynamic SQL:

```
SET @message = 'EXCEPTION: Msg ' + COALESCE(CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR(20)), '[NULL]') + ', ' +
   'Level ' + COALESCE(CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS NVARCHAR(20)), '[NULL]')  + ', ' +
   'State ' + COALESCE(CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS NVARCHAR(20)), '[NULL]') + ', ' +
   'Procedure ' + COALESCE(@PROCEDURE_NAME, '[NULL]') + ', ' +
   'Line ' + COALESCE(CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(20)), '[NULL]') + ', ' +
   'Message: ' + COALESCE(ERROR_MESSAGE(), '[NULL]') ;
```

I'm having trouble getting the quotes down so that it looks like this when it's executed in the dynamic SQL. How should the quotes be arranged in the following:

```
EXEC @sql = 'BEGIN TRY
...
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
DECLARE @PROCEDURE_NAME NVARCHAR(128);
SET @PROCEDURE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID);

END CATCH
';
```

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't posted in full. I'm trying to make edits right now but for some reason it's not allowing me to.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to SET @message in the dynamic SQL and I'm having trouble with the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message code looks fine.

However, if you want to embed your @message in dynamic SQL, then you have to double every single quote.

This is a pain to do by hand.  So, I do the following:

1. Write the SQL as you have done.
2. Select it.
3. Type H (or choose  from the menus).  Put a single quote (`'`) in the search box, and two single quotes (`''`) in the replace with box.
4. Replace everything in the *selection*.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Sorry for the question being incomplete...I'm having problems with my network that wasn't allowing me to submit, then it submitted incomplete, and now I can't edit the post.

Comment: I sometimes have problems uploading things as well.  I'm not sure if it is Stackoverflow or the proxie server on this end.  Often, editing the post in strange ways makes it postable.  And then the problem seems to disappear.